# Specifying component in the children empty path or the parent

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This post is to get second opinion on the following matter. Here are the two routes that configure component for the `/tasks` URL. I've tested and they seem to be equivalent. Now I'm wondering which one is preferred. Assume that there are other children in the routes marked with `...`.

So, the first one where component is specified alongside the `path`:

```
export const tasksRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tasks',
    component: ExTasksComponent,
    children: [
      ...
    ]
  }
];
```

And the second where the component is specified in the empty path of the `children` node:

```
export const tasksRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tasks',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ExTasksComponent
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
];
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: They're not equivalent. In the first example the template for `ExTasksComponent` will be displayed for **all child components**, whereas in the second example the template for `ExTasksComponent` will be displayed **only once**. The question is "do all the routes starting with `path...` have markup in common (e.g. a navigation bar) that you can wrap in a parent component"?.

Comment: @AngularFrance, can you please clarify, I don't understand what you mean. Inside the `ExTasksComponent` template there's `<router-outlet>` and this is where other children's components will be rendered in. This is true for both configurations.

Comment: In the first example, the parent template is still displayed for every children even if it only contains `<router-outlet>` (I would agree it's a bit of a waste to have a component/template just to hold the outlet). Anyways, my point was your two examples aren't exactly equivalent. More specifically, `ExTasksComponent`'s template won't have the same markup in example #1 and example #2, so maybe the structure of your markup can help you decide the best setup.

Comment: @AngularFrance, thanks, but I'm still not following. Can you please provide a URL or modifications to the configuration for which there will be difference?

Comment: I honestly don't know what to add... Maybe you're overthinking this. What I said is common sense really. You can implement the two configurations with mock markup in all components and it should become plain as day.

Comment: @AngularFrance, thanks, I've run through some experiments and I understand what you mean now. Thanks. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is slightly opinion based, the second one will be more benecifial.

savkin stated: *Componentless routes “consume” URL segments without instantiating components* in: http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes

So you will be instantiating the base component unnecessarily when navigating to other child routes otherwise.